# Quarkus App does not launch, no failure message

Tags: intellij-idea, quarkus

I am trying to launch a simple quarkus app from Intellij with `Quarkus.run(Dummy.class, args)`

The output doesnt say whats wrong, no erros, nothing, just exits with 1

```
Press [h] for more options>
Tests Paused
..
..
..
Press [h] for more options>

Process finished with exit code
```

Has anyone seen this before? I am going into a rabbit-hole debugging into the Quarkus tree but I am sure I am missing something very silly.

Any advice is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Differences with vanilla JAX-RS

> With Quarkus, there is no need to create an Application class. It’s supported, but not required. In addition, only one instance of the resource is created and not one per request. You can configure this using the different *Scoped annotations (ApplicationScoped, RequestScoped, etc).

Check https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started for more details. I suggest to use https://code.quarkus.io/ to starting quarkus project which gives a running code inside.